# SceneKit Update Method for Physics Simulation

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8, scenekit

I have played with sprite kit and have used the update method to set things to process each time step.  I'm trying to learn some swift with scene kit and can't seem to find the equivalent.

Can you point me to an example of implementing an update method for SceneKit?  Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

(Yes, I know this question is about **SceneKit**, not SpriteKit, but it touches on the commonalities and differences between the two frameworks, so I'll address those in this answer.)

In SpriteKit, the game-loop methods (`update`, `didSimulatePhysics`, etc) were originally part of the scene class `SKScene`. This isn't always the best idea, though — you might want to treat a scene instance more like data than like a place to implement game logic (especially now that scenes can be built completely in the Xcode 6 graphical scene editor).  So in iOS 8 and OS X Yosemite, those methods are in two places. If you're already subclassing `SKScene` for per-frame game logic, you can keep doing that. But if you'd rather put that code elsewhere, you can set a delegate on your scene, and implement the equivalent [`SKSceneDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKSceneDelegate_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014319) methods there.

SceneKit has more of a separation of concerns. An `SCNScene` is much closer to being a pure data-model object, and all rendering-loop functionality managed by the view (or other object) responsible for displaying the scene. Typically you display a scene in an `SCNView` — but there are other classes that can render scenes, too, so their common API is found in the [`SCNSceneRenderer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNSceneRenderer_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012016) protocol. Use the `delegate` property defined by that protocol to set a delegate for your view, and in your delegate you can implement [`SCNSceneRendererDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNSceneRendererDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012017) methods to participate in key phases of the render loop.

The SceneKit loop phases correspond almost directly to those in SpriteKit: `update:` becomes `renderer:updateAtTime:`, `didEvaluateActions:` becomes `renderer:didApplyAnimationsAtTime:` (because it includes CoreAnimation-style animations as well as SpriteKit-style actions), etc.

---

So, for the SceneKit equivalent of the SpriteKit per-frame `update` method, do this:

1. Set one of your custom objects (say, a view controller) as the `delegate` of your `SCNView` instance.
2. In that custom class, implement the following method:

   ```
   func renderer(_ aRenderer: SCNSceneRenderer!, updateAtTime time: NSTimeInterval) {
       // per-frame code here
   }
   ```

Or do similar for the other `SCNSceneRendererDelegate` methods if your per-frame logic needs to happen after actions or physics have been processed.

Comment: I tried this... and it isn't quite right yet.    What do you think the issue is?  I'm quite confused. 

override func renderer( _ aRenderer: SCNSceneRenderer!,
        updateAtTime time: NSTimeInterval)
    {
         println("Hello\n")
    }

Comment: It's not an override method on any particular subclass — see edited answer.

Comment: I wonder why they are using system time here? Wouldn't that break things if the clock changed?

Comment: Hi, I know this is an old post, but I was wondering if you could provide a more in-depth example of how to follow those steps you set out, particularly Step 1, or at least point me to a good, detailed resource on SceneKit programming in this way.  Thank you very much for posting such a complete answer though (at least, for people who know more about Swift than me).